# Springcloud stream rabbit reliable delivery

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I'm not clear about reliable delivery for producer side of "springcloud stream rabbit" mentioned on the official website. Could anybody provide an example? Thanks in advance.

As mentioned by [SpringCloud Stream rabbit](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/docs/3.1.0.M1/reference/html/index.html#rabbit-prod-props)

> confirmAckChannel
> When errorChannelEnabled is true, a channel to which to send positive delivery acknowledgments (aka publisher confirms). If the channel does not exist, a DirectChannel is registered with this name. The connection factory must be configured to enable publisher confirms.

> Default: nullChannel (acks are discarded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little involved, but here is an example.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So63131155Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So63131155Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So63131155Application.class, args);
    }

    private final Map<UUID, BlockingQueue<ReturnedAmqpMessageException>> returned = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private final Map<UUID, BlockingQueue<Boolean>> confirms = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    private StreamBridge bridge;

    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> input() {
        return str -> {
            UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
            log.info(uuid.toString());
            Message<String> msg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(str.toUpperCase())
                .setHeader(AmqpHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, uuid.toString())
                .build();
            this.returned.put(uuid, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
            this.confirms.put(uuid, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
            this.bridge.send("output-out-0", msg);
            try {
                Boolean confirm = this.confirms.get(uuid).poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                this.confirms.remove(uuid);
                if (confirm == null) {
                    log.warn("Remove " + uuid);
                    this.returned.remove(uuid);
                    throw new RuntimeException("No confirm received");
                }
                log.info(confirm.toString());
                BlockingQueue<ReturnedAmqpMessageException> returnQ = this.returned.get(uuid);
                // We have to wait a short time here due to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1055
                // Arrival of return before confirm should be guaranteed by the framework.
                ReturnedAmqpMessageException returnedEx = returnQ.poll(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                this.returned.remove(uuid);
                if (returnedEx != null) {
                    log.error(returnedEx.toString());
                    throw new RuntimeException("Message returned");
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "acks")
    public void handleAcks(Message<?> msg) {
        this.confirms.get(UUID.fromString(msg.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, String.class)))
            .add(msg.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.PUBLISH_CONFIRM, Boolean.class));
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
    public void handleErrors(Message<?> msg) {
        log.info(msg.toString());
        if (msg.getPayload() instanceof ReturnedAmqpMessageException) {
            ReturnedAmqpMessageException exception = (ReturnedAmqpMessageException) msg.getPayload();
            log.info(this.returned.keySet().toString());
            this.returned.get(UUID.fromString(exception.getAmqpMessage().getMessageProperties().getCorrelationId()))
                    .add(exception);
        }
    }

}
```

Obviously, with a batch listener, you can wait for the confirms/returns after the whole batch has been sent, which will improve performance.

There is currently a bug in Spring AMQP (noted in the code, with a crude work-around) which will be fixed soon.

I have also opened a [new feature issue here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues/303) to make this all much easier.

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0.group=foo

spring.cloud.stream.source=output
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output-out-0.producer.error-channel-enabled=true

spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input-in-0.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output-out-0.producer.confirm-ack-channel=acks

spring.rabbitmq.publisher-confirm-type=correlated
spring.rabbitmq.publisher-returns=true

logging.level.org.springframework.integration=debug
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I tried your code, however, code under annotations "@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "acks")" and @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel") in your example are not invoked. Is there any other configuration need to set in configuration file? E.g. confirmAckChannel.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the `application.properties`. Done.